# Why do I have different values in Environment variables?

Tags: .net, powershell, environment-variables, windows-11

When I do:

`[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path') -split ';'`

or

`$env:path -split ';'`

I get this result, which has bunch of duplicates
[image]

but when I open the environment variables from control panel, I see this:

[image]

I'm using a standard account and PowerShell is running as standard too, trying to modify the current user's Path.

I tried closing and reopening PowerShell and restarting the computer, but I still see different values between control panel and PowerShell output. why is that?

p.s I previously used .NET in PowerShell to add a location to the path variable of my current standard user, and the variables weren't originally like that, I was just trying some thing with them and ended up like that, but I cleaned the duplicates in control panel, I just can't get the PowerShell to show the correct cleaned version of them. I have no idea at which point I messed it up but I need to know why I'm getting different results.

Comment: Here is a reference for you just in case you need it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Path` environment variable returned by `GetEnvironmentVariable` consists of merged `Path` from User variables and System variables. The provided screenshot seems to show only `Path` from User variables, check System variables `Path` also (and check it for duplicate entries).

Comment: Thank you, but I have 1 question, with your help I figued I have to use this to limit its scope to user variables only `[Environment]::getEnvironmentVariable('path', 'user') -split ';'` but how can I set the scope of `$env:path` to user or system? since it also shows the combined variables of user plus system.

Comment: This is a new (followup) question and it's better to start a new question next time. $env is scoped to the current session. Changes are gone when the session closes and there is no way to alter that.  For all other functionality you need the [Environment] methods.